# How to user input filename with a specific extension?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to create a program using python that was will user input a fasta file that can later be used to trim primers. I am trying to use BioPython to do this but I keep running into errors. The code I have tried is as follows:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

in_file = input("Enter filename with extension:")

def is_fasta(in_file):
    with open(in_file) as handle:
        fasta = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
        return any(fasta)

is_fasta(in_file)
```

I want to be able to ask for a fasta file and if the inputted file isn't fasta, show an error message and prompt to try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with Python's `try` statement? You can just try to open and read the file and if it doesn't work (i. e. raises an exception) you prompt the user again.

I don't know `Bio.SeqIO` or even the `Bio` module. I guess the error comes with the line containing your call to `SeqIO.parse`? You can try something like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

while True:
    in_file = input("Enter filename with extension:")
    try:
        with open(in_file) as handle:
            fasta = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
    except:
        print("Could not read file. Please ensure it is a 'fasta' file and try again.")
        continue
    break
```

Without exception, the assignment of `fasta` should have worked and we'll break out of the `while` loop with `break`.